# Как скомпилировать проект который уже загружен на хостинг?

Tags: c#, хостинг

Вообщем, я залил своего дискорд бота на хостинг, теперь не могу найти в интеренте нормального гайда, как его запустить, подскажите как скомпилить своего бота на хостинге.

Comment: `dotnet build`...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можно дать пожалуйста, подробный ответ

Comment: http://legendminds.in/how-to-run-net-core-console-app-on-linux/